# Is this translated right?

Tags: grammar

茶の初穂を飲むと憎まれる, 幸福は共有されることによって決して減少しない

cha no hatsuho wo nomu to nikumarer, Kōfuku wa kyōyū sa reru koto ni yotte kesshite genshō shinai'

One shouldn’t drink a good tea by oneself, it’s better to share it with others. Happiness never decreases by being shared.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly yes, and the first part is actually
[common saying explained here](http://www.ocha.tv/words/ta_06/index.html) (site in Japanese). It explains that the very first tea leaves harvested were believed to bear the best aroma and flavor (and thus could be a blessing to be shared as you write in the latter part).

Comment: Is this something I can write in these words? I mean is the grammar and everything in order to be understanded. I printing this for a book and I need to know if its right.

Comment: In that case it is best to go to an actual proofreading site. I believe that in as much we would like to help you, it is discouraged by the [community guidelines](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799), which recommends Lang-8 or HiNative instead.